# spring integration: inbound channel adapter. catch an exception

Tags: spring-integration

I implemented a sftp-inbound-channel-adapter, and when an exception is handled , i should display a customized message.

I tried :

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
    auto-startup="true" channel="receiveChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    local-directory="file:${directory.files.local}" remote-directory="${directory.files.remote}"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="true"  
    filename-pattern="*.txt" >
    <int:poller fixed-delay="${sftp.interval.request}"
        max-messages-per-poll="-1" />

<int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>

<bean: class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">

<property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload" />
<property name="successChannel" ref="afterSuccessDeleteChannel" />
<property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File(payload.absolutePath + '.failed.to.send'))" />
<property name="failureChannel" ref="afterFailRenameChannel" />
</bean>
</int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

But an element

`<int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>`

is not accepted. Can you explain another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request handler advice goes on some downstream component, not an inbound channel adapter.

You can add an `error-channel` to the `<poller/>` element. The message sent to the error channel will be an `ErrorMessage` with the exception as a payload. If it's an exception on the downstream flow, the payload will be a `MessagingException` with `failedMessage` and `cause` properties.

Add some component to consume the error messages.